# C# Windows 10 Mobile Bluetooth BLE - OnAdvertisementReceived

Tags: c#, windows, bluetooth, windows-mobile, win-universal-app

I'm trying to learn how to use BLE in C# with my Windows 10 Mobile smartphone.
I'm currently trying to connect to my Oral-B toothbrush in order to get data off it.

Unfortnately in my code "OnAdvertisementReceived" never gets called and I don't know why, the toothbrush is BLE enabled and using an analyzer app on my android smartphone I can see that it is sending beacons/advertisments in order to get connected, but the text of my debug- textbox doesn't change.

Here's my complete C# code:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        // Create and initialize a new watcher instance.
        watcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();
        watcher.SignalStrengthFilter.InRangeThresholdInDBm = -70;
        watcher.SignalStrengthFilter.OutOfRangeThresholdInDBm = -75;
        watcher.SignalStrengthFilter.OutOfRangeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);

        watcher.Received += OnAdvertisementReceived;

        watcher.Stopped += OnAdvertisementWatcherStopped;

        App.Current.Suspending += App_Suspending;

        App.Current.Resuming += App_Resuming;
    }

    private void App_Suspending(object sender, Windows.ApplicationModel.SuspendingEventArgs e)
    {
        watcher.Stop();
        watcher.Received -= OnAdvertisementReceived;
        watcher.Stopped -= OnAdvertisementWatcherStopped;

    }

    private void App_Resuming(object sender, object e)
    {
        watcher.Received += OnAdvertisementReceived;
        watcher.Stopped += OnAdvertisementWatcherStopped;
    }

    private async void OnAdvertisementReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "true";
        var address = eventArgs.BluetoothAddress;

        BluetoothLEDevice device = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(address);


        var cnt = device.GattServices.Count;

        watcher.Stop();
    }

    private void OnAdvertisementWatcherStopped(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherStoppedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {

    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        watcher.Start();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you set up a Permission in `Manifest` file? `<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth" />
  </Capabilities>`

Comment: I am facing similar problem. I am using Lumia 1520 that was upgraded to W10 Mobile. I was told by some Microsoft Techies that there is a problem with the older Lumia's and that it should work fine on the 550, 950 & 950XL. I wonder what is your test device?

Comment: I think at least in Windows 10 desktop it looks like even LE devices need to be paired first. Have you tried that?